# Having trouble with Inner Join SQL

Tags: php, sql

I've got two tables:

Cyclist = `Dob`, `name`, `ISO_id`

Country = `country_name`, `gdp`, `population`, `ISO_id`.

I need to query to get the Cyclist.name, Country.country_name, Country.gdp, Country.population.

Using two dates which are entered by the user. These two dates are used to search all cyclists who were born between the dates.

This is what i've tried so far:

```
SELECT Cyclist.name, Country.country_name, Country.gdp, Country.population
FROM Cyclist
INNER JOIN Country
ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id
WHERE Cyclist.dob between '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

however it's not working and I dont know why.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: First of all, check values of `$date1` and `$date2` (it would be nicer if you replace them with real values in query here).

Comment: What if you execute your query without the 'WHERE-Statement'.
Does it return anything?

If yes, your where-statement is wrong. Why are you using quotes for Cyclist.dob?

Comment: @PLB i've changed them to real values. Still nothing.

Comment: @ Fabian it works without the Where statement. Thankyou. now i know what to fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT Cyclist.name, Country.country_name, Country.gdp, Country.population
FROM Cyclist
LEFT JOIN Country
ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id
Cyclist.dob>='$date1' and Cyclist.dob<='$date2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use left join for select all right recods from Cyclist and extend response by data from Country:

```
SELECT Cyclist.name, Country.country_name, Country.gdp, Country.population
FROM Cyclist
LEFT JOIN Country
ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id
WHERE `Cyclist.dob` between '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have enclosed whole Cyclist.dob in WHERE clause, You need seperate enclose both Cyclist and dob to work like.

```
SELECT Cyclist.name, Country.country_name, Country.gdp, Country.population
FROM Cyclist
INNER JOIN Country
ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id
WHERE `Cyclist`.`dob` between '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However that's not the problem. When i removed the WHERE clause it started working however even when i put real values into $date1 and $date2 it did not.

Comment: When you remove where clause you also remove problem I indicated, As I check similar code on mysql it gave error if you enclosed whole block. Or even you can completely ignore the backtick character in where clause and use something like that `WHERE Cyclist.dob between ... `